# Distributing objects on containers

Tags: optimization, entropy

Suppose we have $n$ containers, each has the ability of holding $f_{i}$ object for $i=1, 2, \dots, n$. That means $f_{i}$ is the maximum number of object that the $i$th container can hold.

Now, we have $N$ objects in total. We assume that $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} f_{i} > N$ such that all $N$ objects can actually be filled into the containers.

**Question:**
How to distribute these objects to the containers such that each container would not reach to its upper limit too quickly?

If $f_{i} \equiv f$ for all $i$, then my intuition told me that the $N$ objects must be uniformly distributed to the containers. (seems related to entropy). But what if all $f_{i}$ are different? What is the objective function?

Answer (score 2):

If you  want to maximize the time until any bin reaches its maximum limit.

At any moment of time, when we want to insert an object, look for a bin with at least $2$ slots left.

That way, if $N\le \sum_{i=1}^nf_i-n-1$, the upper limit for every bin is not attained.

If $N \ge \sum_{i=1}^nf_i-n$, then we don't have a choice but let one of the bin attain the maximum.

Comment: How did you obtain the inequality constraint?

Comment: Intuitively, when we have too many objects, we have no choice but to hit an upper limit. Now, the question is what is having too many objects. My proposed strategy is to avoid hitting any upper limit whenever we can. The first moment when we can't avoid is when every bins has exactly $1$ slot left. Total number of slots is $\sum_{i=1}^n f_i$, and the number of bins is $n$.

Comment: Thanks. Apart from just avoiding hitting the upper limit, I would like to distribute the objects such that every containers would have enough buffer. Not sure what are the keys word to search for this problem. My feeling is that it is related to entropy, but I am not sure.

Comment: would have enough buffer?  is it that some objects must go to certain bins only?

Comment: well yes, there are some constraints on what are the available containers for each object. But I tried to ignore these constraints first for simplicity.

Comment: do we know those labels in advance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88068/discussion-between-k-inverse-and-siong-thye-goh).